# R function used argument is fixed?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, arguments

i have a question for another problem, but i tried breaking it down to a simpler code, so that my initial problem is visible. I tried making a dataframe and a function computing the sum as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(1,2,3))

fun <- function(data,x,y){

    z <- sum(data$x) + sum(data$y)
    return(z)
}

fun(data= df,x = df$x,y = df$y)
[1] 12
```

The code gives me the expected sum 12. Changing the colnames of the df dataframe to e.g "r" and "t"
returns 0, even if i specify the arguments in the function. What is wrong?

```
  df <- data.frame(r=c(1,2,3),t=c(1,2,3))

    fun <- function(data,x,y){

        z <- sum(data$x) + sum(data$y)
        return(z)
    }
    
    fun(data= df,x = df$r,y = df$t)
[1] 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-character-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the second function is trying to extract the variables `x` and `y` from the `data`. It is equivalent of doing `data[["x"]]` which is not your intention.

Instead, we could pass the variables as characters to get intended results and converting the extraction from `data$x` to `data[[x]]`:

```r
df <- data.frame(r=c(1,2,3),t=c(1,2,3))

fun <- function(data,x,y){
  
  z <- sum(data[[x]]) + sum(data[[y]])
  return(z)
}

fun(data= df,x = "r",y = "t")
#> [1] 12
```

For this particular example, we could use a base approach and use `with()` that is pretty clean:

```r
with(df, sum(r) + sum(t))
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot, also for my other code. Actually, you can use single paranthesis [] in the function as well, right?

Comment: I believe a single bracket on a ```data.frame``` returns a ```data.frame``` whereas a double bracket returns a vector. I am not at a computer to confirm. I think a vector is better for ```sum()```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest next approach. It looks like your code when using `$` looks for a dataframe. Instead you could try this:

```
#Data 1
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(1,2,3))

#Function

fun <- function(data,x,y){
  
  z <- sum(x) + sum(y)
  return(z)
}

#Apply

fun(data= df,x = df$x,y = df$y)
```

Output:

```
[1] 12
```

Now second example:

```
#Apply 2

df <- data.frame(r=c(1,2,3),t=c(1,2,3))

fun(data= df,x = df$r,y = df$t)
```

Output:

```
[1] 12
```

Comment: It looks like that the `data` argument in `fun()` is redundant because you don't call it anywhere.

Comment: @DarrenTsai Yes you are right, but it is better if you set things close as OP issue so that they understand. Your comment is pretty useful :)